# Python Keyboard Module doesn't work without root

Tags: python, keyboard

Currently, I have written a code for a voice assistant which can write with users voice. I use python keyboard module from pip. But when I execute the code it shows me that it cannot write without root.

the code is given below,

```
elif (t.find("type") != -1):

    le = t.find("type") + len("type") + 1
    t = t[le:]
    try:
        print("Typing> ", t)
        keyboard.write('' + t+". ")
    except:
        print("Can't Type")
```

Comment: Yes, this is true, and [documented](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/): "To avoid depending on X, the Linux parts reads raw device files (/dev/input/input*) but this requries root." Did you have a question?

Comment: Is there any way to write with keyboard module without root access ?

Comment: In my opinion it's totally unacceptable to run arbitrary python programs as root.  On my linux system there exists a group "input" which have full permissions to /dev/input/* - it should suffice to add myself to this group.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot read or write using the keyboard module unless you are running as root. I have had the same problem, sadly. But Pynput worked perfectly using the `pynput.keyboard.Listener` class.

Comment: This actually works! `keyboard` forcing me to use root was killing my entire workflow